# SPARQL: DISTINCT keyword is not working with VALUES

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have a SPARQL query as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?class
FROM <http://data.latize.com/context/User>
WHERE {
    VALUES ?k {<http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Machine/Script> <http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Person/Editor>}
    ?k rdfs:subClassOf* ?class.
}
```

and it returns the following output (in JSON)

```
[
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Machine/Script,
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Machine,
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount,
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account,
    http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing,
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Person/Editor,
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Person,
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount,
    http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account,
    http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
]
```

For some reason, `http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount`, `http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account` and `http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing` is repeating even though I have used the DISTINCT in the query. 
Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Your results are distinct for each value. If you want them distinct for all values, make your graph patterns with them together, not sequentially.

Comment: You mean like to use FILTER instead of VALUES? Something like `FILTER (?k = <http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Machine/Script> || ?k = <http://data.latize.com/vocab/Account/NamedAccount/Person/Editor)`?

Comment: Sorry, I had a wrong assumption about when then binding was made. In this case, as long as you are asking for one variable, both should produce the same results.

Comment: Which triple store do you use?

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov what do you mean by *"distinct for all values"*? `VALUES` is more a less a shortcut for `UNION` in this case - the last operation must be a distinct on all rows

Comment: @AKSW indeeed, see my second comment. My assumption was that a particular implementation of SPARQL may apply distinct for the result set of each value and then simply combine the result sets.

Comment: Hm, ok. That would be strange and incorrect afaik. But it would be interesting to know which SPARQL engine is used here.